# How to create a specific Role for a CodeBuild Step in an AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

It seems there's a circular dependency here:

1. `pipeline.buildPipeline()` must be called before any points where CDK code refers to the Pipeline role
2. If specifying a Role for a Step, the Pipeline must be able to Assume the Role (if you let the Step Construct create the Role for you, Assumption privileges will be automatically grants)
3. `assumedBy` is a mandatory field in Role creation, and a Role's `assumeRolePolicy` is immutable
4. The Role of a CodeBuild Step is immutable
5. Any changes made to a pipeline after calling `pipeline.buildPipeline()` will be discarded. Specficially, a call  to `stage.addPost(step)` will have no effect

So, then:

- 1., 2, and 3. => The Role must be created after calling `.buildPipeline()`
- 4. => The Step must be created after the Role
- 5. => `.buildPipeline()` must be called after creating the Step

And so, a contradiction.

Have I missed something somewhere?

(As for *why* I would want to do this when it's possible to set `rolePolicyStatements` directly in the Step constructor - setting a static name, or tagging the Role with `Tags.of(role).add(...)`, are two reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about the constraint in #2?  I believe the Step role requires the CodeBuild service principal, not the pipeline, in its trust policy.

```js
const step = new pipelines.CodeBuildStep("MyStep", {
  role: new iam.Role(this, "MyCustomRole", {
    roleName: "MyCustomRoleName",
    assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("codebuild.amazonaws.com"),
  }),
  // ...
});
```

If that doesn't work because the L2 logic is somehow too constraining, consider the CDK [escape hatches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html).  Start with the step's default role and override its properties as needed:

```js
pipeline.buildPipeline();

const cfnRole = (myStep.project.role as iam.Role).node.defaultChild as iam.CfnRole;

cfnRole.addPropertyOverride("RoleName", "MySpecialRoleName");
```

Comment: D'oh - you're completely right, I'm not sure how I came to that wrong assumption. Thanks!